# An crash of AutoCompleteTextView in Android 7.0, for Samsung Phone model

Tags: android, crash, textview, samsung-mobile, android-7.0-nougat

I use an AutoCompleteTextView as a input box for URL, it works fine on android 6.0 and below. But recently, as Samsung push the update for its android system to android 7.0, we received many crashes. The phone model contains: 
SM-N920V    422
SM-G955U    549
SM-G925F    685
SM-G920V    418
SM-G920F    1045

No other Phone model found except Samsung.

The log just below:

```
03-14 15:57:54.973 E/AndroidRuntime(  564): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
03-14 15:57:54.973 E/AndroidRuntime(  564):     at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3714)
03-14 15:57:54.973 E/AndroidRuntime(  564):     at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3375)
03-14 15:57:54.973 E/AndroidRuntime(  564):     at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3660)
03-14 15:57:54.973 E/AndroidRuntime(  564):     at android.widget.Editor.replace(Editor.java:423)
03-14 15:57:54.973 E/AndroidRuntime(  564):     at android.widget.Editor$3.run(Editor.java:2340)
03-14 15:57:54.973 E/AndroidRuntime(  564):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
03-14 15:57:54.973 E/AndroidRuntime(  564):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-14 15:57:54.973 E/AndroidRuntime(  564):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-14 15:57:54.973 E/AndroidRuntime(  564):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6724)
03-14 15:57:54.973 E/AndroidRuntime(  564):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-14 15:57:54.973 E/AndroidRuntime(  564):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
03-14 15:57:54.973 E/AndroidRuntime(  564):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

So who can tell me what happened? Why does this crash only find in Samsung android 7.0 and what we can do to avoid it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I have worked around that, but you can see the link below to solve the problem

Comment: There's no solution in that link.

Comment: @HaloperShine did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It's a Samsung bug. See [this link](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/android-app-crash-because-of-null-pointer-exception-on-setting-onclick-listener-in-editor-class/201/309993?boardName=SDK&startId=zzzzz~)